# Drawing an infinite grid in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I would like to know the best way to create an infinite grid on an iOS app I'm building. I use internal hardware on an iPhone to gather real-world data and build vectors. I'd like to visually represent the vector data on this grid that sort of acts like a graph. Each vector is represented as a line, and each new vector is attached to the previous vector on this grid. I'm building the app so that it can run for however long the user wants (from minutes - hours). The only problem I'm having trouble facing is how to start with this grid. I imagine the line on the app can get pretty long if the user runs the app for a couple of hours, so the grid needs to accommodate it and be "infinite" in that manner.

By infinite, I mean that the user can swipe up, down, left, or right on the grid and the lines that make up the grid never end. There's just always going to be a grid on the screen regardless of where they swipe or for how long they swipe. The grid should also take on the properties of a graph as mentioned previously. I'm hoping to get something close to this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708, but this graph cuts off.

I did some research, and most of the questions asking about grids come from the SpriteKit framework. But I don't know if running a game engine is the best solution. I would like to use core graphics, but if it's not possible to do this on that framework, I can work off of any other suggestions. Any help on where to start is appreciated!

Comment: Fair to assume this would be in Swift?

Comment: Yes this is in swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample project to illustrate what needs to be done.  The code can be found at: https://github.com/ekscrypto/Infinite-Grid-Swift

Essentially, you start with a very simple UIScrollView in which you assign a "reference" view that will become the (0,0) point initially.  You then set ridiculously large distance between your reference view and the scrollview content edges (enough so user can't possibly scroll non-stop without stopping) and adjust the contentOffset so that your view fits in the middle of the scroll view.

You then have to observe the contentOffset of the scrollview and figure out how many tiles on each side are required to fill the screen and some more, so that when the user scrolls there's always content to show.  This can be set to any number of tiles but be careful to keep this reasonable as your tiles will likely consume memory.  I found 1 full screen width/height to be sufficient for even the fastest of manual scrolls.

As the user will scroll, the contentOffset observer will be called, allowing you to add or remove views as required.

When the scrollview is done animating, you will want to reset the point of reference so you don't run out of contentOffset to use.

Assuming a relatively simple "GridTile" class, which will be instantiated to fill in the grid:

```
protocol GridTileDataSource {
    func contentView(for: GridTile) -> UIView?
}

class GridTile: UIView {

    let coordinates: (Int, Int)

    private let dataSource: GridTileDataSource

    // Custom initializer
    init(frame: CGRect, coordinates: (Int, Int), dataSource: GridTileDataSource) {
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.isOpaque = false
    }

    // Unused, not supporting Xib/Storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        populateWithContent()
    }

    private func populateWithContent() {
        if self.subviews.count == 0,
            let subview = dataSource.contentView(for: self) {
            subview.frame = self.bounds
            self.addSubview(subview)
        }
    }
}
```

And starting with a relatively simple UIView/UIScrollView setup:
[image]

You can create the GridView mechanics as such:

```
class GridView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var hostScrollView: UIScrollView?
    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    private(set) var allocatedTiles: [GridTile] = []
    private(set) var referenceCoordinates: (Int, Int) = (0,0)
    private(set) var tileSize: CGFloat = 0.0

    private(set) var observingScrollview: Bool = false
    private(set) var centerCoordinates: (Int, Int) = (Int.max, Int.max)

    deinit {
        if observingScrollview {
            hostScrollView?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset")
        }
    }

    func populateGrid(size tileSize: CGFloat, center: (Int, Int)) {
        clearGrid()
        self.referenceCoordinates = center
        self.tileSize = tileSize
        observeScrollview()
        adjustScrollviewInsets()
    }

    private func clearGrid() {
        for tile in allocatedTiles {
            tile.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        allocatedTiles.removeAll()
    }

    private func observeScrollview() {
        guard observingScrollview == false,
            let scrollview = hostScrollView
            else { return }
        scrollview.delegate = self
        scrollview.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .new, context: nil)
        observingScrollview = true
    }

    private func adjustScrollviewInsets() {
        guard let scrollview = hostScrollView else { return }

        // maximum continous user scroll before hitting the scrollview edge
        // set this to something small (~3000) to observe the scrollview indicator resetting to middle
        let arbitraryLargeOffset: CGFloat = 10000000.0
        topConstraint?.constant = arbitraryLargeOffset
        bottomConstraint?.constant = arbitraryLargeOffset
        leftConstraint?.constant = arbitraryLargeOffset
        rightConstraint?.constant = arbitraryLargeOffset
        scrollview.layoutIfNeeded()
        let xOffset = arbitraryLargeOffset - ((scrollview.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.width) * 0.5)
        let yOffset = arbitraryLargeOffset - ((scrollview.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) * 0.5)
        scrollview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset), animated: false)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard let scrollview = object as? UIScrollView else { return }
        adjustGrid(for: scrollview)
    }

    private func adjustGrid(for scrollview: UIScrollView) {
        let center = computedCenterCoordinates(scrollview)
        guard center != centerCoordinates else { return }
        self.centerCoordinates = center
        //print("center is now at coordinates: \(center)")
        // pre-allocate views past the bounds of the visible scrollview so when user
        // drags the view, even super-quick, there is content to show
        let xCutoff = Int(((scrollview.frame.size.width * 1.5) / tileSize).rounded(.up))
        let yCutoff = Int(((scrollview.frame.size.height * 1.5) / tileSize).rounded(.up))
        let lowerX = center.0 - xCutoff
        let upperX = center.0 + xCutoff
        let lowerY = center.1 - yCutoff
        let upperY = center.1 + yCutoff
        clearGridOutsideBounds(lowerX: lowerX, upperX: upperX, lowerY: lowerY, upperY: upperY)
        populateGridInBounds(lowerX: lowerX, upperX: upperX, lowerY: lowerY, upperY: upperY)
    }

    private func computedCenterCoordinates(_ scrollview: UIScrollView) -> (Int, Int) {
        guard tileSize > 0 else { return centerCoordinates }
        let contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
        let scrollviewSize = scrollview.frame.size
        let xOffset = -(self.center.x - (contentOffset.x + scrollviewSize.width * 0.5))
        let yOffset = -(self.center.y - (contentOffset.y + scrollviewSize.height * 0.5))
        let xIntOffset = Int((xOffset / tileSize).rounded())
        let yIntOffset = Int((yOffset / tileSize).rounded())
        return (xIntOffset + referenceCoordinates.0, yIntOffset + referenceCoordinates.1)
    }

    private func clearGridOutsideBounds(lowerX: Int, upperX: Int, lowerY: Int, upperY: Int) {
        let tilesToProcess = allocatedTiles
        for tile in tilesToProcess {
            let tileX = tile.coordinates.0
            let tileY = tile.coordinates.1
            if tileX < lowerX || tileX > upperX || tileY < lowerY || tileY > upperY {
//                print("Deallocating grid tile: \(tile.coordinates)")
                tile.removeFromSuperview()
                if let index = allocatedTiles.index(of: tile) {
                    allocatedTiles.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func populateGridInBounds(lowerX: Int, upperX: Int, lowerY: Int, upperY: Int) {
        guard upperX > lowerX, upperY > lowerY else { return }
        var coordX = lowerX
        while coordX <= upperX {
            var coordY = lowerY
            while coordY <= upperY {
                allocateTile(at: (coordX, coordY))
                coordY += 1
            }
            coordX += 1
        }
    }

    private func allocateTile(at tileCoordinates: (Int, Int)) {
        guard existingTile(at: tileCoordinates) == nil else { return }
//        print("Allocating grid tile: \(tileCoordinates)")
        let tile = GridTile(frame: frameForTile(at: tileCoordinates),
                            coordinates: tileCoordinates,
                            dataSource: self)
        allocatedTiles.append(tile)
        self.addSubview(tile)
    }

    private func existingTile(at coordinates: (Int, Int)) -> GridTile? {
        for tile in allocatedTiles where tile.coordinates == coordinates {
            return tile
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func frameForTile(at coordinates: (Int, Int)) -> CGRect {
        let xIntOffset = coordinates.0 - referenceCoordinates.0
        let yIntOffset = coordinates.1 - referenceCoordinates.1
        let xOffset = self.bounds.size.width * 0.5 + (tileSize * (CGFloat(xIntOffset) - 0.5))
        let yOffset = self.bounds.size.height * 0.5 + (tileSize * (CGFloat(yIntOffset) - 0.5))
        return CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: tileSize, height: tileSize)
    }

    // readjustOffsets() should only be called when the scrollview is not animating to
    // avoid any jerky movement.
    private func readjustOffsets() {
        guard
            centerCoordinates != referenceCoordinates,
            let scrollview = hostScrollView,
            tileSize > 0
            else { return }
        let xOffset = CGFloat(centerCoordinates.0 - referenceCoordinates.0) * tileSize
        let yOffset = CGFloat(centerCoordinates.1 - referenceCoordinates.1) * tileSize
        referenceCoordinates = centerCoordinates
        for tile in allocatedTiles {
            var frame = tile.frame
            frame.origin.x -= xOffset
            frame.origin.y -= yOffset
            tile.frame = frame
        }
        var newContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
        newContentOffset.x -= xOffset
        newContentOffset.y -= yOffset
        scrollview.setContentOffset(newContentOffset, animated: false)
    }
}

extension GridView: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        guard decelerate == false else { return }
        self.readjustOffsets()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.readjustOffsets()
    }
}

extension GridView: GridTileDataSource {

    // This is where you would provide the content to put in the tiles, could be
    // maps, images, whatever.  In this case went with a simple label containing the coordinates
    internal func contentView(for tile: GridTile) -> UIView? {
        let placeholderLabel = UILabel(frame: tile.bounds)
        let coordinates = tile.coordinates
        placeholderLabel.text = "\(coordinates.0, coordinates.1)"
        placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        placeholderLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return placeholderLabel
    }
}
```

Then all that is left, is to kick start your GridView by specifying the grid size and the initial coordinate to use:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gridView: GridView?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        gridView?.populateGrid(size: 150.0, center: (0,0))
    }
}
```

And there you have it, an infinite grid.

Cheers and Good Luck!

Comment: Let me look over this in detail, and ill get back to you. Code would be a big help, but thanks for the fast response regardless!

Comment: I just want clarification on my understanding of your answer in lamens terms. So, you pretty much just have a screen showing your music notes, but when the user moves far enough to left (for example), you cut the "piece" of notes all the way to the right (which would no longer be on the screen anymore) and just tack it on to the farther left side to provide the sense of infinity. And the process pretty much repeats itself both ways. When you add the "new piece of grid" to the farther left side, are you generating the new piece, or is it simply copy, cut, and paste to the other side?

Comment: If you could post that sample project, that would be great. I went through this but didn't really have any luck since this is my first time working with ScrollViews and Outlets in this much detail. If you have the time of course!

Comment: There you go, enjoy!