# How can I efficiently draw an infinite grid that you can pan and zoom?

Tags: ios, uikit

I am trying to create a grid that's...

- Infinite in all directions.
- Can be panned horizontally and vertically.
- Can be zoomed.

My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544588/drawing-an-infinite-grid-in-ios) because I need my grid to be zoomable.

My current solution uses a UIBezierPath in drawRect. The problem with this (and the solution to the linked question above) is that it maxes the CPU and the experience is very choppy.

How should I approach this problem broadly? Thank you!

Comment: Isn’t this what CATiledLayer is for?

Comment: Though I fail to see what you can mean by infinite.

Comment: I don't think CATiledLayer is the right tool for the job. 

Basically, imagine an infinitely large sheet of graph paper. Now put a scroll view on top of it. The user can pan in any direction without reaching a limit, and zoom at any point (I do have a minimum scale factor). 

Basically, in my view's drawRect I will draw a bunch of vertical and horizontal lines from one edge to the other. As the user scrolls, I redraw the view with an offset.

Comment: @DanubePM have you ever figured it out?

Comment: Not really, sorry. @haik.ampardjian